# Concatenating results from a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, do-while

```
String lottoNumbers = "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("To buy a ticket we need your numbers...");


        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter number " + i);
            int userNum = scan.nextInt();

            if (userNum >= 1 && userNum <= 49) 
            {
                lottoNumbers = lottoNumbers + userNum;
                if (i < 6) lottoNumbers = lottoNumbers + ", ";
            }

            else
                do {
                    System.out.println("Numbers must be between 1 and 49. \nPlease try again.");
                    userNum = scan.nextInt();
                    }
                while (userNum <1 || userNum >49);
        }   

        System.out.println("You selected numbers " + lottoNumbers);
        System.out.println("Ticket has been printed, please pay £2.");
```

So the purpose of this is we are practicing for, do, do while loops. We are to create this do while loop where user enters 6 numbers between 1 and  49. If they enter outside this range they need to reenter until their input is between 1 and 49.

The issue I have is if they enter all 6 within 1 - 49 first time, the output is concatonated correctly, i.e "Your numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"

But if they mess up say the 4th entry, the output will miss this. I.e "Your numbers are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6"

Not quite sure where I'm going wrong here. Please note we have not long started Java and I'm limited in the type of solution I can use at this stage.

The psuedo code I had to follow is:

```
1.1.    Declare a String variable to hold the output
1.2.    Declare scanner variable
1.3.    Print “To buy a ticket we need your numbers…”
1.4.    Loop 6 times
1.4.1.  Print “Please enter lotto number x”
1.4.2.  Declare variable to hold users num
1.4.3.  Store users num
1.4.4.  If number is between 1 and 49 then
1.4.4.1.1.  concatenate the users number plus a comma to the output
1.4.5.  Else
1.4.5.1.1.  Do Loop
1.4.5.1.1.1.    Print “numbers must be between 1 and 49 please try again”
1.4.5.1.1.2.    Store users num
1.4.5.1.2.  Loop While users num < 0 or users num> 49
1.4.6.  End If
1.5.    End Loop
1.6.    Print “You selected numbers “ + output
1.7.    Print “Ticket has been printed – please pay £2”
```

Comment: Isn't it because your for loop runs just for 6 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user inputs a number out of range in the main loop, your catch-up `do { } while ( )` loop does not process the input. It checks for validity, sure, but it doesn't use it anywhere.

What you need to do is, once the user corrected himself in the catch-up loop, append the value to the string.

```
if (userNum >= 1 && userNum <= 49) {
    lottoNumbers = lottoNumbers + userNum;
    if (i < 6) lottoNumbers = lottoNumbers + ", ";
} else {
    do {
        System.out.println("Numbers must be between 1 and 49. \nPlease try again.");
        userNum = scan.nextInt();
    } while (userNum < 1 || userNum > 49);
    // Process valid input here
    lottoNumbers = lottoNumbers + userNum;
    if (i < 6) lottoNumbers = lottoNumbers + ", ";
} // Note the extra brackets around else block
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I forgot all about dealing with the corrected input.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your else section, you ask the user to enter a new number, and you save this but you don't add/concatenate it to your String lottoNumbers.

Also, I'd be careful where you do add this from the else loop so you don't end up adding an extra number by mistake.